# How to decide between Listener and Visitor?

Tags: antlr4

I'm using Antlr4, C# version under Visual Studio. Works nicelly.

AFAIK (but I may be wrong) Listeners and Visitors are used for similar tasks.

So, how to decide between them? Or can I use both? Note that all the samples I've found uses Listener OR Visitor, but not both...

Comment: Try one and see if it works. If not, try the other. In the meantime, I am still using the legacy actions but they just work as I wished.

Comment: Both works. My last project with Antlr4 was done with Visitor and worked. On another project I used Listener and worked either.

Comment: Some tasks are easier with listeners, others are easier with visitors. Use the one which fits best. For instance, for tree rewriting, you'd better use visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion he visitor is a good choice because you have full control of the traversal

Here is quote from the book "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference"

> The biggest difference between the listener and visitor mechanisms is that listener methods are called by the ANTLR-provided walker object, whereas visitor methods must walk their children with explicit visit calls. Forgetting to invoke visit() on a node’s children means those subtrees don’t get visited

If you translate the input to a lower level, e.g. virtual machine instructions, both patterns may be useful.

Comment: I guess that "you have full control of the traversal" is the key point here. Anyway, I think that there are some cases where Listeners are the ideal way. Thanks for your answer, @Nappy Boy.